# How to make selected option disabled in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

Following is my code for select tag.
I want to disable the option that has been selected

How to achieve this?

```
<td> 
  <%= select("gu", "rm_id", Rm.where(category_id: Admin.select("category_id").where(id: current_user.id)).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {prompt: 'Assign RM'},{onchange: "update_rm_div(this.value,#{gu.id})"}) %>
</td>
```

Any help is appreciatable

Comment: try using this with jquery

Comment: in success can i make it disabled?

Comment: Try using  $("#selectId option:selected").remove();

Comment: this removes that option and when i reload that page it again comes with that option.

Comment: can i give any css color to the selected one?

Comment: Do you want to delete that option permanently?

Comment: no , i want to make it just disabled, disabling is working but on refresh disabled option disappears. any idea?

Comment: $("#gu_rm_id option:selected").prop( "disabled", true );

Comment: In this case you should store the selected value in session.And change the property on runtime.

Comment: :) thanks kajal let me try

Comment: Hi, Can you post your complete `form` in your question? I don't think you need `jQuery` for `disable` an option.

Comment: or try something like chosen to handle your select: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/